# How to get second value from array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I seem to have hit many snags trying to get to this point so I'm quite surprised I've even got this far.

I'm trying to get a role name (from roles table) through the users table

I currently have:

```
{{ Auth::user()->role }}

Which gives me:

Role : 1 [{"id":1,"name":"Float","created_at":"2018-03-19 00:00:00","updated_at":"2018-03-19 00:00:00","pivot":{"user_id":1,"role_id":1}}]
```

But once I try:

```
{{ Auth::user()->role->name }}

I get:

Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Surely that should work? the name field is clearly there in the array.

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: As this is a `Collection`, you can use `...role->first()` instead of `...role[0]` to access the first element in the `Collection` (preference though). Also, note that `role` should really be `roles` (plural vs singular), as `role` suggests only a single entity, but you're actually receiving 1 or more.

Comment: May I ask you which relationship you're using? Because if you are using the HasOne relation you could just simply do `{{ Auth::user()->role->name }}`, because a user can only have _one_ role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the `name` property exists in the **array**. The object exists within an array, and you need to access the array first, specifying which index of `role` you wish to access:

```
{{ Auth::user()->role[0]->name }}
```

Comment: Brilliant mate, I tried with the brackets with 1 or  name in there too. urgh so close. Thanks.

Comment: What happens when the array role is empty. Shouldn't we check for that before calling `->role[0]`?

Comment: Assuming they have no roles than you obviously won't be able to get the role name, and yes, it's best to check that as well :) However, I'd personally opt for checking against an **individual** role that you want to do something with. Depending on exactly what you want to do with the role, you *could* check for a specific role with something like `if($request->user()->hasRole('user'))`.